# Hide Approve/Reject from Ribbon and from More Actions Menu

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We have a workflow task that sets the document to approved when 3 people hit approve on the Workflow Task. Untill three people hit approve from the task the document will stay in pending.

However, we can't stop the document going to approved when a User with Approval rights hits Approve from either the top ribbon or the "More Actions" menu if you right click the document and hit Approve/Reject from there.

Is there anyway we can disable this on this Library, either through CEWP or similar?

This is on SharePoint 2016 Enterprise.